# Devise, rspec and Mongoid test failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mongoid

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before(:each) do
    @attr = {
      :username => "User",
      :email => "aaaaer@example.com",
      :password => "foobar",
      :password_confirmation => "foobar",
      :phone_no => "0808322222"
    }
  end

  it "should create a new instance given a valid attribute" do
    User.create!(@attr)
  end
end
```

The test keep failing, please dont know why

```
Failures:

  1) User should create a new instance given a valid attribute
     Failure/Error: User.create!(@attr)
     Mongoid::Errors::Validations:
       Validation failed - Phone no can't be blank, Username can't be blank.
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.2505 seconds
2 examples, 1 failure
```

Comment: We need the model to know where is your error inside. Maybe you use attr_accessible or attr_protected

Comment: @shingara I have pasted the User model at https://gist.github.com/1835904 I am using attr_accessible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is you define some data by #create method where data is not is attr_accessible attribute.

So you can add this attribute on your attr_accessible list of you can avoid using the mass-assignement by example :

```
  it "should create a new instance given a valid attribute" do
    u = User.new
    @attr.each do |k,v|
      u.send("#{k}=", v)
    end
    u.save!
  end
```

Comment: I used this snippet you provided and had this error:

  1) User should create a new instance given a valid attribute
     Failure/Error: u.send(k"=", v)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `k' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x000000045fac18>
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:17:in `each'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

I commented out the attr_accessible line in the model and the test passed, so I know where to look, I would fix it later, thanks alot

Comment: Sorry, I fix my snippet with `send("#{k}=", v)`